# PHP: How to insert a <br/>-tag after the @ inside an email address

Tags: php

I'm having problems with some email addresses that are too long. So I'd like to set a break after the `@` character.

But unfortunately, the `@` symbol seems to be a special character. That's why it doesn't work with:

```
str_replace ('@' , '@<br/>' , $email);
```

Is there any other way to get it done?

Comment: Please show us your **full** and **real** code. The shown code should work as expected, as long as you assign it back to the variable

Comment: You are making wrong assumptions which in turn makes your question impossible to sanely answer

Comment: if u want to break it into 2 parts use `explode('@',$email)`

Comment: Tested your code *as is*, and it returned `asfasfsdfasfasfassfd@`
`asdffasfasdfdssf.com` on 2 seperate lines and this in HTML source `asfasfsdfasfasfassfd@<br/>asdffasfasdfdssf.com`

Comment: you posted your question two days ago and asked for help and received both a comment and an answer by myself. You need to work with us here and post any comments you may have, including additional code you're probably not showing us; please respond.

Answer (score 0):

I'll make an attempt at hopefully answer this question, seeing that you are most likely not showing us your full code.

If by any chance that you're using another function in conjunction with this, say for example `strlen()`, then that could account for it, and how you're using it.

You may also be using another function, which is unknown at the time of your posting. Therefore you will need to elaborate on that, should my answer not provide you with a solution.

- *Far as I'm concerned,* your "posted" code checked out, so I can't see how that could be failing.

Using the following and in conjunction with your posted code, proved to be successful.

```
<?php 
// email with 33 characters
$email = "emailwith33characters@example.com";

// if more or equal to 33 characters
if(strlen($email) >= 33){
    echo "The email <b>$email</b> contains 33 or more characters. ";
    echo "Now putting them into 2 lines...";

    echo "<br>";

// echo str_replace('@', '@<br/>', $email);
    echo "First line: " . str_replace('@', '@<br/>Second line: ', $email);
}

else{
    echo "Email is within character limit.";
}
```

Using `echo strlen($email);` will show you the email's string length.

---

Reference(s):

- http://php.net/strlen
- http://php.net/str_replace

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help. Unfortunately "str_replace" does not work with the "@" character in my code. If I test it with the "." character it sometimes works. Ever time I reload the page in the browser the "str_replace" result changes.

Here's some more of the code. It's from a Wordpress plugin to show contact details of staff members. It loops through all staff posts.

```
        $i = 0;
    if( $staff->have_posts() ) {
        if ($headline =='yes') {
            $output .= '<h1 class="staff-group-mainheader">'.$maingroupname.'</h1>';
        }
        $output .= '<div class="staff-member-listing '.$group.'">';

        while( $staff->have_posts() ) : $staff->the_post();
            unset($staff_member_classes);

            $terms = get_the_terms( $post->id, 'staff-member-group' ); // get an array of all the terms as objects.

            $term_slug = array(); // save the slugs in an array
            $term_name = array(); // save the slugs in an array
            foreach( $terms as $term ) {
                $term_slug[] = $term->slug; // this grabs the hyphenated slug
                $term_name[] = $term->name; // this grabs the actual name
                $staff_member_classes .= ' '.$term->slug;
            }

        if ($i == ($staff->found_posts)-1) {
            $staff_member_classes .= " last";
        }

        if ($i % 2) {
            $oddorevenpost = 'even';
        } else {
            $oddorevenpost = 'odd';
        }

        if (($oddorevenpost == $oddoreven) || ($oddoreven == '')) {

            $output .= '<div class="staff-member '.$oddorevenpost.' '.$staff_member_classes.'">';

        global $post;

        $custom     = get_post_custom();
        $name       = get_the_title();
        $name_slug  = basename(get_permalink());
        $title      = $custom["_staff_member_title"][0];
        $function   = $custom["_staff_member_fb"][0];
        $email      = antispambot($custom["_staff_member_email"][0]);

        if (!empty($custom["_staff_member_phone"][0])) {
            $phone = '<li><i class="icons lycon-phone"></i><span class="staff-phone">'.$custom["_staff_member_phone"][0].'</span></li>';
        }
        if (!empty($custom["_staff_member_mobile"][0])) {
            $mobile = '<li><i class="icons icon-mobile-6"></i><span class="staff-mobile">'.$custom["_staff_member_mobile"][0].'</span></li>';
        }
        if (!empty($custom["_staff_member_fax"][0])) {
            $fax = '<li><i class="icons lycon-fax"></i><span class="staff-fax">'.$custom["_staff_member_fax"][0].'</span></li>';
        }
        $company    = $custom["_staff_member_company"][0];
        $street     = $custom["_staff_member_street"][0];
        $city       = $custom["_staff_member_city"][0];
        $country    = $custom["_staff_member_country"][0];
        $bio        = $custom["_staff_member_bio"][0];



        if(has_post_thumbnail()){

            $postidthumb = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID));
            $photo_url = wp_get_attachment_medium_url( $postidthumb );
            $photo = '<div class="staff-member-container" style="background: url('.$photo_url.') no-repeat right bottom;">';
        }else{
            $photo_url = '';
            $photo = '';
        }


        if (function_exists('wpautop')){
            $bio_format = '<div class="staff-member-bio">'.wpautop($bio).'</div>';
        }
        $emailbreak = str_replace ('@' , '@<br/>' , $email);

        $email_mailto = '<li><i class="icons icon-mail-7"></i><span class="staff-email"><a class="staff-member-email" href="mailto:'.$email.'" title="Email '.$name.'">'.$emailbreak.'</a></span></li>';
        $email_nolink = antispambot( $email );

        $accepted_single_tags = $default_tags;
        $replace_single_values = array($name, $name_slug, $photo_url, $title, $function, $email_nolink, $phone, $mobile, $fax, $company, $street, $city, $country, $bio, $fb_url, $tw_url);

        $accepted_formatted_tags = $default_formatted_tags;
        if ( $title =='') {
            $formattedname = '<h3 class="staff-member-name">'.$name.'</h3>';
        } else {
            $formattedname = '<h3 class="staff-member-name">'.$title.' '.$name.'</h3>';
        }
        $replace_formatted_values = array($formattedname, '<h4 class="staff-member-position">'.$title.'</h4>', $photo, $email_mailto, $bio_format );

        $loop_markup = str_replace($accepted_single_tags, $replace_single_values, $loop_markup);
        $loop_markup = str_replace($accepted_formatted_tags, $replace_formatted_values, $loop_markup);

        $output .= $loop_markup;

        $loop_markup = $loop_markup_reset;



        $output .= '</div> <!-- Close staff-member -->';
        }
        $i += 1;

        endwhile;

        $output .= "</div> <!-- Close staff-member-listing -->";
    }
}

wp_reset_query();

$output = $style_output.$output;
```